# Restricting the action of a script to one window during the whole life of the script

Tags: autohotkey

I wanted to write an AutoHotKey script to draw the object blah in a colour chosen from a list by the user. Once the script is activated, the first choice is printed on the command line:

draw( blah, White)

- n cycles forward through the colours,
- N cycles backwards,
- Esc clears the command line and exits the script,
- Enter sends enter to the command line thus firing off the draw command,
- Otherwise, do nothing.

This is my inelegant attempt:

```
#IfWinActive Command Prompt
^z:: 
i := 0
loop
{
mod_i := Mod(i,7) 
if(mod_i = 0)
col := "White"
else if(mod_i=1)
col := "Orange"
else if(mod_i=2)
col := "Purple"
else if(mod_i=3)
col := "Green"
else if(mod_i=4)
col := "Red"
else if(mod_i=5)
col := "Blue"
else if(mod_i=6)
col := "Yellow"

send {Esc} draw (blah, %col% )


Input, OutputVar, L1, {Enter}{Escape}

IfInString, ErrorLevel, EndKey:
{
;ErrorLevel is set to the word EndKey followed by a colon and the name of the EndKey
if ErrorLevel = EndKey:Enter
{
send {Enter}
break   
}
else if ErrorLevel = EndKey:Escape
{
send {Esc}
break   
}
}
if (OutputVar == "n")
i++
else if (OutputVar == "N")
i--

; break out after 20 loops
if (A_Index > 20)
break
}
return
```

Which seems to work. However if the script is in operation and another window is activated, the script acts on that window. Which is to be expected I suppose with the current implementation. So is there a way to limit a scripts action to one window? Possibly pausing the script when the window is inactive?

If I can be cheeky and ask a second question; is there a more efficient way to implement a cyclical list in AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) rather than send.

```
ControlSend, , {Esc} draw (blah, %col% ), Untitled - Notepad
```

Obviously you would change the last parameter to be the title of the program or ahk_class/exe.

Comment: I've found that [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) can be a bit unreliable when sending text. I recommend using a [KeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) to prevent dropped inputs. (`SetKeyDelay, 5`)

Answer (score 0):

The hotkey continues to run even after the window is closed, you need to check at the end of each iteration whether or not the active window is a command prompt.

If it's not use the 'break' command to end the loop.